# Dynamic routes for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to have a routes that would look like such:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/trial/:extention/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/quran.html', controller: 'QCtrl'});
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/page/1'});
```

Where i can put `'/trial/someExtention/1'` or `'/trial/someExtention/1/1/5'`

Problem is, when I do `'/trial/someExtention/1'` it sends me to the otherwise route while I'd like for it to be able to do both without sending to otherwise

Comment: Not to nitpick, but your route definition starts with a forward slash - does it work when you put that in the url?

Comment: Yes it does with no problems, no different than this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: Could you please try the route ending by `:id/`and `:id*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "catchall" route rule like this: `:ids*`

This tells the router to store everything after /:extension/ into the ids route-parameter. Your `$routeProvider` can look something like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when( '/:extension/:ids*', { 
      templateUrl: 'this.html',
      controller: 'routeCtrl'
    })
    .when( '/that', { templateUrl: 'that.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/that' } );
```

The `/:extension/:ids*` will then catch both "/Something/1" and "/Someotherthing/1/2/3". The ids route-parameter will in the last case have the value "1/2/3". You can split up this into an array if you want, like this in your controller:

```
$scope.ids = $routeParams.ids.split("/");
```

I have created a **plunker** here if you want to take a closer look: http://plnkr.co/edit/EZqMtnbRs0lKc07hnenQ?p=preview

**Update**: You can also specify optional route-parameters like this, if you don't want to store everything into a single id-variable:

```
$route$routeProvider
    .when( '/:extension/:id/:id2?/:id3?', { 
      templateUrl: 'this.html',
      controller: 'routeCtrl'
    })
```

The `?` at the end signals that the parameter is optional.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically for `'/trial/someExtention/1'` you configuration should work fine, just in case take a look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gRLLP/2/

If you want to catch both `'/trial/someExtention/1'` and `'/trial/someExtention/1/1/5'` with one rule, you may use new feature (as far as I remember it was introduced in  v1.1.5):

set rule like this - `'/trial/*extension/add'`
[Details about * rule](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24routeProvider)

BTW, here is the commit with [changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7eafbb98c64c0dc079d7d3ec589f1270b7f6fea5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use templateUrl as function where you can play with your url parameters

```
$routeProvider.when('/subscriber/update/:action', {
    templateUrl: function(para){
       return 'partials/subscribers/'+ para.action +'.html';
    },
    controller: 'SubscriberController'
}).otherwise({
 redirectTo: '/'
});
```